# Opposite category functor

Tags: category-theory, self-learning

I need some confirmation: is the opposite category transformation always a functor?

Also, isn't it always the case that $C^{\text{op}} = C$, since the the way we label an arrow does not matter?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "always" here. "Opposite category" is a single functor $\text{Cat} \to \text{Cat}$ from the category of (say, small) categories to itself.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: You're right, "always" should not be there. Thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a silly example. Form a category with objects $a,b,c$ and morphisms $f:a\to b,g:a\to c$ (and identities). This category has an initial object, namely $a.$ On the other hand, its opposite category clearly does not have an initial object ($a$ becomes terminal). Thus the two categories must be distinct.

Comment: Not so silly :)

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks, for giving an example helped me "see it".

Comment: Dear @Andŕe, you're welcome, I hoped as much!

Answer (score 7):

The objects of $\mathcal C^{\text{op}}$ are exactly the same as the objects of $\mathcal C$.

The morphisms of $\mathcal C^{\text{op}}$ are backwards versions of the ones in $\mathcal C$.

If we have a morphism $A \color{green}{\longrightarrow} B$ in $C$, we have a morphism $B \color{blue}{\longrightarrow} A$ in $\mathcal C^{\text{op}}$.

These are different categories because there might be a morphism $A \color{green}{\longrightarrow} B$ in $C$ but no morphism $A \color{blue}{\longrightarrow} B$ in $C^{\text{op}}$.

There is a contravariant functor $$ \begin{array}{rrcl} &\text{Dual}&:& \mathcal C \longrightarrow \mathcal C^{\text{op}} \\ &\text{Dual}(A)&=& A \\ &\text{Dual}(A \overset{f}{\color{green}\longrightarrow} B)&=& B \overset{f}{\color{blue}{\longrightarrow}} A \end{array}$$ which is an isomorphism of categories though.

Comment: This functor is *not* an isomorphism of categories! An isomorphism of categories is by definition given by a covariant functor. This functor is contravariant and therefore not considered an isomorphism of categories.

Comment: @Must I think he is talking about the functor $\mathtt{Cat}\to\mathtt{Cat}$, which would be covariant.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, going from $C$ to $C^{op}$ is a contra-variant functor.

The equality $C^{op}=C$ is not true. Don't be misled by the fact that these two categories have exactly the same objects. The morphisms differ, and recall that a category is not simply the collection of objects, rather the objects together with the morphisms.

Comment: Why contravariant?

Comment: If $F$ is the functor $C \rightarrow C^{op}$, and $f:A \rightarrow B$ is a morphism in $C$, then $F(f)$ will be a morphism from $B=F(B)$ to $A=F(A)$. By definition of the opposite category, arrows from $A$ to $B$ in $C$ are viewed as arrows from $B$ to $A$ in $C^{op}$.

Comment: Ahh... I thought, it is about the $()^{op}$ functor...

Comment: Depending on foundations, $C^\circ$ also has the same morphisms as $C$ -- the difference is in the composition, source, and target operations. For the category corresponding to an abelian group, we would even have $C^\circ = C$ as a true equality.

Comment: @Hurkyl: and before posting this question, I was looking at $Mat$, the category of matrices. Just to be sure, in this case it is true that $Mat^{\text{op}} = Mat$, right?

Comment: @Andre: Nope, because (in the formulation I'm referring to) by definition, $A \cdot_{\text{op}} B = B \cdot A$ (multiplication on the right is in $Mat$ and on the left is in $Mat^\circ$) and there exist $A$ and $B$ such that $B \cdot A \neq A \cdot B$.  If $Mat^\circ = Mat$, then $\cdot$ and $\cdot_{\text{op}}$ would be the same operation.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, there is a functor $Cat\to Cat$ that maps $C\mapsto C^{op}$ and maps a functor $F:C\to D$ to the corresponding $C^{op}\to D^{op}$.
2. No. Direction does matter. Well, how to say, it is easy to figure out $C^{op}$ once we know $C$, but these are not equivalent, neither identical.

Comment: But sperners lemma's answer above gave an isomorphism $Dual : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}^{op}$, so $\mathcal{C}$ must be equivalent to $\mathcal{C}^{op}$.

Comment: @DávidTóth That's not an isomorphism. Because it is not a covariant functor.